# Displaying UI message before upload on iOS

Tags: fine-uploader

My Fine Uploader instance is working fine. Great product and thank you!!
I'm using the JQuery method of implementation.

The issue I'm running in to is on iOS6 (iPad.)

When I select many files (say 6 or more) there is a long pause where nothing happens before the auto upload triggers.

What I'm trying to do is display a dialog to the user during this awkward pause to say "hold on we're processing the files" or something.

I've already tried to throw the dialog in onSubmit, onSubmitted it's simply too late. The pause happens, THEN the dialog appears. I just want the user to not be left hanging during this awkward pause, as I'm dealing with very non-savvy users.

I tried to throw it on validateBatch but I'm doing something wrong.

So finally my question is this:
How/where (which callback or event) would I go about throwing a message to my users after they have selected their files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are describing a very specific bug in iOS6.  I created a [bug report](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/857) in the Fine Uploader project that covers this.  I also opened up a bug report with Apple.

The issue is that Safari on iOS (possibly Chrome too, though I have not verified) takes a noticeable amount of time to trigger the "onchange" event (which Fine Uploader depends on internally) after a user has selected files.  The amount of time it takes iOS6 to trigger this event seems to be proportional to the number of files selected at once.  This issue in particular is not related to Fine Uploader as it can be reproduced with a simple file input element on an empty page (as indicated in the bug report I linked to).

I'm afraid there is no workaround for this, as far as I know.  When a user selects a file or files via a file input element, Fine Uploader has no way of knowing about this until the browser triggers the "onchange" event on the file input.

Note: The bug report I linked to may not load at the writing of this answer as Github is currently down (and has been for a while now).

Comment: Thanks Ray! I will check the bug reports more thoroughly in the future.

Comment: There is no possible workaround.  Hopefully Apple will fix this at some point.